# CSS not including style in html class

Tags: html, css

.tittle is ok. 
.flavor does not acknowledge the changes.
HTML class="flavor" does not show style when rendering the webpage.

```
 <div class="title">
        <h1> HEAVENS ICE CREAM </H1>
        <div> 1 </div>
        <div> 2 </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flavor">
          <div>
            <p> Peach </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p> Coconut </p>
          </div>
    </div>

.title
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  color: red;
  background-color: grey;
};

.flavor
{
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  color: blue;
};
```

Comment: Remove the semi colons after your brackets in your css. https://jsfiddle.net/ad6yxe5z/1/

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. your `h1` tag is incorrect for the `.title`.
2. semicolon `;` is not needed end of css selector.

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  color: red;
  background-color: grey;
}

.flavor {
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1> HEAVENS ICE CREAM </h1>
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
</div>

<div class="flavor">
  <div>
    <p> Peach </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> Coconut </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things
- After calling for CSS, no semicolon is needed at the end
- Put the CSS into a style tag. Without the style tag, HTML cannot reference the CSS without the clarification of what this code is
(Like so)

```
<style type="text/css">
.title 
{ 
display: flex; 
flex-direction:
row-reverse;
color: red; 
background-color: grey;
} 
.flavor 
{ 
display: flex; 
background-color: grey; 
color: blue; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, the html and css are in different files.  With this clarification, what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Oh, kk. Try to include how you linked the CSS within the HTML

Comment: I finally made it. But now I ran into another problem.  The <img src=""> are not rendering.   My project folder looks like this: |_heavensIceCream  |_ _ _ main.html style.css   |_resources  |_ _ _ peach.png .     my img tag looks like this: `<img scr="./resources/peach.png" alt="peach" />`

Comment: Lol, yep there is the problem